# why const_cast is not allowed for unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, constants, unique-ptr

I am trying to const_cast unique_ptr and it is giving me error :

```
  const std::unique_ptr<int> myptr;
  std::unique_ptr<int> myptr1 = std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<int> >(myptr));
```

So I want to understand why const_cast doesn't work with unique_ptr if it can work with normal pointers ?

Comment: Naturally, you can't move from a const object: move needs to modify the source, in order to "steal" resources from it.

Comment: so this means i cannot have vector of const std::unique_ptr right ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you indeed cannot. vector's elements must be either copyable or movable, and `const unique_ptr` is neither.

Comment: You cannot have a vector of `const int`, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can const cast a unique_ptr. What you can't do is move from a const unique_ptr, which is what your code attempts to do. You could do this though:

```
vec.push_back(std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<int>&>(myptr)));
```

Of course, this is undefined behavior, since your unique_ptr is actually const. If `myptr` was instead a const reference to a unique_ptr which was not actually const, then the above would be safe.

In your new code

```
std::unique_ptr<int> myptr1 = std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<int> >(myptr));
```

The const cast tries to copy `myptr` before passing the result to `std::move`. You need to cast it to a reference in order to not copy it.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> myptr1 = std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<int>& >(myptr));
//                                                                     ^
```

Comment: @Kapil: Yes. We can. What you can't do is copy a unique_ptr, which your new code attempts to do.

Comment: no even this std::unique_ptr<int> myptr1 = std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<int> >(myptr)); doesn't compile

Comment: @Kapil: Because that's still attempting to copy the unique_ptr, in the const_cast itself. You need to cast it to a reference.

Comment: @Kapil: i.e. `std::unique_ptr<int> myptr1 = std::move(const_cast<std::unique_ptr<int>&>(myptr));`

Comment: the "in the new code" suggestion is still undefined behaviour (modifying a const object)